# Is Forbidden Forest east or west of Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

In Prisoner of Azkaban (Ch 16), Rowling describes Forbidden Forest as seemingly being to the **west** of the castle:

> Walking very close together so that nobody would see them, they crossed the hall on tiptoe beneath the cloak, then walked down the stone front steps into the grounds.
>
> The sun was already sinking behind the Forbidden Forest, gilding the top branches of the trees.

So..  `[setting sun]<-[forbidden forest]<-[characters going from castle].`

The sun sets in the West; so forbidden forest is westward of the Castle.

---

However, JKR apparently produced a drawing showing that Forbidden Forest was to the **east** of the castle *(according to DVD supplementary materials, the drawing was done by JKR at a hotel dining table for Stewart Craig, production designer for Philosopher's Stone film, when he started his work on the movie)*.

**Is there any indication of which one is canonically correct and how we are supposed to reconcile the difference?**

[image]

Comment: Is there a compass on the map that I am missing? Can't north be at the bottom of the map?

Comment: @NominSim - the text orientation points to the fact that the forest is "right", which means it's East. That is a standard convention. **Typically, maps show east on the right**; and the map is oriented Hogwarts left based on text. Sources1: ["South-up map orientation places the labeling on a map so that south is up, north is down, east is left and west is right. Thus the Southern Hemisphere appears at the top of the map instead of the usual bottom. **Maps in this orientation are sometimes called upside down maps or reversed maps**"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South-up_map_orientation)

Comment: @NominSim:  Source 2: ["Today, the most common – but far from universal – cartographic convention is that North is at the top of a map"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map#Orientation_of_maps) (the latter lists some maps that aren't north-up, but Hogwarts map doesn't seem to plausibly fall into those, e.g. non-Western maps)

Comment: Where is that image from?

Comment: @NominSim: There's no compass so we can't be certain either way. Gotta find another reference.

Comment: @Voldemort - http://www.hp-lexicon.org/atlas/hogwarts/atlas-h-jkrmap.html

Comment: Well, in all fairness, since clearly the book is canon and Rowling's map should be canon too, the map must indeed be rotated. The only thing that holds me back is a [claim by Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Places_in_Harry_Potter#Hogsmeade) that Hogsmeade is supposedly to the north-west of Hogwarts - but such claim seems to lack a source. A wild guess is that Wikipedia saw the map and they also assumed that it was unrotated. I too find it strange that Rowling decided to draw a rotated map, though.

Comment: @Voldemort - this could be resolved if there are other directions elsewhere in the book (e.g. is the Lake to the North or South?)

Comment: @DVK I'm glad you mentioned the lake! Its position on the hand-drawn map you've provided above is at odds with the description in the books. In GoF, the Hogwartians are waiting at the front steps to the Entrance Hall for the arrival of the Beauxbatons and Durmstrang delegations. Somehow, the students are able to see the Durmstrang ship rising out of the lake, when, according to the map, the lake is on the other side of the castle. I think this compromises the reliability of the map. Maybe it can't be considered canon?

Comment: This happens in Chapter 15, Beauxbatons and Durmstrang, pg 216, Bloomsbury Edition.

Comment: Worth an answer.

Comment: Further, the lake is not likely to be north from the castle, because the Hogwarts Express comes from the south and the first-years cross the lake.

Comment: I feel like the map has to be wrong. The link states that JKR put it together in "just a few minutes" (and so clearly, with no reference to the written text). The quote above (sun sinking behind the forbidden forest) was probably chosen for style reasons (it sounded good at the time) and not for the purposes of locating it relative to the other landmarks within the school grounds.

Comment: Not sure the comments about the lake actually help the situation here though. I don't have the books to hand so haven't checked, but it would seem there is nothing on the map or in the text of PoA to suggest that the front steps of Hogwarts have to face the forest, and not the lake. Granted the two lines in Chapter 16 as quoted above follow each other, but there is nothing to say that the characters wouldn't have had to turn to the side (after walking down the steps), one way or the other, to see the sun sinking behind the Forest. Or am I missing some other detail?

Comment: No, there is definitely no way that the students, who are literally waiting on the top of the "sloping lawns" right in front of the double front doors, could possibly see the lake if we are to take the hand-drawn map at its word that the lake is "behind" the castle. In my head, I've always imagined the lake to be somewhere to the left ("left" according to this map) of the Quidditch Stadium, because of this scene alone. The lake must be visible from the front doors that lead into the Entrance Hall - a room I really wish they had in the films, as in the early videogames, but I digress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a repeat of an answer I wrote in the comments. I'm just placing it here as an official answer.

The Forbidden Forest should canonically be considered west of Hogwarts because, as DVK quotes in the question, the sun sets behind the Forbidden Forest. As per common knowledge, the sun rises in the east and sets in the west. The books are the most reliable sources of canon we have. As The Giant of Lannister puts it in the comments, the map was hand-drawn by J.K. Rowling in "just a few minutes" probably without direct reference to her books. It is very much possible that Rowling may have made a continuity error in drawing this map. The biggest indicator of this is evidenced in her positioning of the lake 'behind' the castle  i.e. on the opposite side of the double front door entrance.

In Chapter 15, *Beauxbatons and Durmstrang*, of *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* the Hogwarts students await the arrival of the delegations from Beauxbatons and Durmstrang on the front lawn:

> When the bell rang early, Harry, Ron and Hermione hurried up to Gryffindor Tower, deposited their bags and books as they had been instructed, pulled on their cloaks and rushed back downstairs **into the Entrance Hall**. The Heads of houses were ordering their students into lines
>
> ... "Follow me, please," said Professor McGonagall, "first-years in front ... no pushing ..."
>
> **They filed down the *front* steps and lined up *in front of the castle***
> (pg 212, Bloomsbury Edt.)

So, from this position, virtually on the cusp of the bottom-most front step, it would not be possible for the students to see the Durmstrang ship arrive in the middle of the lake - if the lake were on the other side of the castle.

> "The lake!" yelled Lee Jordan, **pointing down at it**. "Look at the lake!"
>
> **From their position at the top of the lawns overlooking the grounds**, they had a **clear view** of the smooth black surface of **the water** ... Some disturbance was taking place **deep in the centre** ... and then, out in **the very middle of the lake**, a whirlpool appeared ... Slowly, magnificently, a ship rose out of the water, gleaming in the moonlight.

This quote explicitly places the lake within a field of vision from the front steps.

---

Now, although I have argued that the map is incorrect, I did notice something new whilst re-reading the first quote that I think must be mentioned:

> (Pg 212 again) They filed down the front steps and lined up in front of the castle. It was a cold, clear **evening**; **dusk** was falling and a pale, transparent-looking **moon** was **already** shining **over the Forbidden Forest** ... "Nearly six," said Ron, checking his watch and then staring at the drive which led to the front gates.

This last quote presents a new problem, I think. If it is dusk, around 6pm, then the moon should be rising over the east, right? According to this scene, east happens to be over the Forbidden Forest - which ties in with the map Rowling has drawn - but this contradicts the sunset in Prisoner of Azkaban (see DVK's quote in the question), which also happens over the Forest, suggesting the Forest's position as to the west of Hogwarts.

I think Rowling may have made some continuity mistakes with the Hogwarts grounds that we can't really make sense out of. It's no big deal, really, it's similar to the mix-up with every September 1st (start of the school year) happening to land on a Monday, the start of the school week; but for the purposes of this discussion, it makes answering the question difficult.

Comment: Actually, [the rising, setting and movement of the moon relative to Earth and Sun is a bit more complex.](http://star-www.st-and.ac.uk/~fv/sky/moon-general.html)  The moon generally rises further to the east, but can, be southeast or northeast depending on time of year and moon phase.  Additionally, there are times when moon rise happens while the sun is still up and the moon's setting happens not terribly long after sun-set.  "The moon was **already** shining over the forbidden forest," does not mean it rose over the forbidden forest and may have already passed its zenith for the evening.

Comment: Yes, the moon differs in its position, but generally speaking, it rises in the east and sets in the west, just like the sun. In this case, that is the main point. I emboldened the word 'already' because that strongly indicates that the moon had just risen, and it was sunset at the time. Even if it was full moon and was closely 'following' the setting sun, that would mean the moon was setting, not rising. Though I'm sure you're right when you say that Rowling probably didn't consider this when she wrote these scenes. It's just a pretty image, having the moon or sun just above the trees.

Comment: See, I don't see the word "already" as indicating it had "just" risen at all, just that it was already visible - meaning a setting moon is also possible here.  However, as I said, she probably didn't think about it that much in reality and it is probably an inconsistency as you point out - simply because it makes for a pretty picture.

Comment: Well, if it's dusk and there's still some sun light, you wouldn't usually expect to see the moon out 'already' - even though it happens quite often. Generally, the sun and moon are not seen together. That's what is meant by "already".

Comment: One week out of a month is exactly what I mean by 'generally'. But you just hit the nail on the head about why Harry is thinking, or Rowling is narrating, that the moon is 'already' out i.e. already risen: People associate day with the sun, and night with the moon.

Comment: If we're getting bogged down in semantics about the definition of 'already' and what it means in this context, let's just agree to disagree :)

Comment: And, besides, if the moon was setting over the Forbidden Forest, that would mean the sun was about to rise. This scene takes place at dusk/evening, which leaves no doubt that the moon is rising.

Comment: The sun and moon both rise in the east and set in the west, but if even they are both visible in the sky at the same time of day, one will be closer to the east horizon and one closer to the west horizon. If the moon has been seen over the Forbidden Forest as the sun sets (in the west), then it follows, logically, that the moon has risen in the east. Again, the word 'already' is a huge clue to this, but you don't seem to understand it. What is your theory, anyway? That the sun and moon are both setting? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: Just for the record, I know that the moon may not "wait" for the sun to set completely before rising, and the sun does not "wait" for the moon to completely set before rising. However, the sun setting indicates where west is, and it is not over the Forbidden Forest, in this case. That's where the moon is. So, since the sun is setting over the Forest in PoA and NOT setting over the Forest in GoF, we have a contradiction. This is the key point for this argument.

Comment: Yes it happens.  For example, on September first, in 1994 (couldn't go back further than that) Moonrise in Edinburgh Scottland would have been at 1:07 am and Moonset at 5:38 pm.  Sunset would have been at 8:08 on that same day in the same place.  http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/astronomy.html?n=304&month=9&year=1994&obj=moon&afl=-11&day=1  While this does not show setting of both at the same time, it was never my intention to say  that was what was happening, simply that they can both be in the Western sky at the same time.  Surely this shows that is possible in Scotland.

Comment: More like, surely J.K. Rowling didn't even think of considering this when she wrote the scenes. This really isn't an argument that necessitates astrophysics and online worldclocks. Many things are possible, including a late moon-rise, but that is not happening in this scene. The point is, Harry was surprised that the moon was "already" risen over the horizon, and the sun was not mentioned over the same horizon, so it wasn't WEST. It's a contradiction. Please, before this discussion gets overly complicated, let's just end it there. Rowling made a mistake, that's it.

Comment: You suggested, a few comments back, that our definitions of the word 'already' in this context differ. Let me explain how I see it (and what I'm certain Rowling meant the reader to see it as): By "already", Harry is thinking (or the narrator is thinking), "Wow, moon, you're here early. The sun hasn't even fully set yet". It's implying a moonrise, not set. If the moon has just risen over the trees, that would make it east. Take the word 'already' out of that quote, and we have a possible moonset. But that isn't the case, sorry.

Comment: I thought you said we should end the discussion?  But okay, already simply means that - already.  For example, "the wheel was already invented."  It has happened before - not necessarily just now or recently but it has happened before.  Since I know adolescents and teens well and they tend to be fairly unobservant I think it may have just been noticed, but all I'm saying is it is *possible* to have a setting sun and moon in the same sky.  Since, on that day, moon set **was** just before six, the only problem is if Durmstrang ship was supposed to have arrived at dusk because dusk is later.

Comment: Also, considering the fact that a huge percentage of the population doesn't seem to even realize moonset and sunset can happen near each-other, a person might think "wow the moon is up already?" even if it has been out all day because they didn't notice it.  **From the beginning, I have said chances were good your main point is true,** but thought you might be interested to know the moon thing **is** possibly **not** a contradiction.

Comment: I did want to end it there, but I couldn't resist writing that thought about defining "already", which is what is meant by the narrator - not Harry specifically, so lets not blame the teens. Also, you seemed to have skirted over the fact that the sun is not said to be directly below the moon, which is over the trees. The sun was setting elsewhere i.e. where west actually lies. And I never had the impression that you were sort-of agreeing with me at all. Maybe that's my oversight, but seeing as this discussion has dragged on so long, I doubt it.

Comment: Anyway, let's just let by gones be by gones ... Officially this time! You think it's possible that the scene in GoF is not at odds with the one in PoA, whereas I see no other explanation. In the end, we agree that it's, at least, highly likely that Rowling made a small error in her mapping of the Hogwarts grounds, right?

Comment: Another mistake in the map: It is clear in the later books that the Hogwarts Express arrives at Hogsmeade station, which should presumably be in Hogsmeade, not the opposite side of Hogwarts from Hogsmeade.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe we can simply say (as suggested in some of the comments) that the map is simply upside down (i.e. the top of the map is south rather than north). Consider the end of *Prisoner of Azkaban* when Harry and Hermione rescue Sirius with Buckbeak.

Dumbledore tells them where Sirius is:

> "Sirius is locked in Professor Flitwick's office on the seventh floor. Thirteenth window from the right of the West Tower.

Now if we assume that the map is reversed (i.e. west is the right side) then we will run into a problem. The thirteenth window from the right of the West Tower would have to be in an eastern direction (coming away from West Tower), i.e. towards the center of the map. In order for it to be *from the right* that would mean that it could not be referring to the front of the castle. If the window was on the front side of the castle then it would be the thirteenth window from the *left*. Now we know that Harry, Hermione, and Buckbeak approached from the front of the castle because right before they flew up to the window they saw Macnair coming out of the castle:

> "Look!" Hermione whispered. "Who's that? Someone's coming back out of the castle!"

Then when they fly up to the window there is no mention that they had to go around to the other side of the castle. We are simply told that they flew up, located the window, and parked there:

> Harry urged Buckbeak forward. They were gliding quietly toward the upper floors of the castle.... Harry pulled hard on the left-hand side of the rope, and Buckbeak turned. Harry was trying to count windows flashing past —
>
> "Whoa!" he said, pulling backward as hard as he could.

Thus, from the fact that they approached from the front of the castle and were able to get to the thirteenth window from the right of West Tower without going around the castle, we know that west must indeed be the left side of the map.

We can derive this from another passage in *Prisoner of Azkaban* as well.

The first time they head to Divination they have trouble finding North Tower. When Hermione suggests a certain passage, we are told the following:

> "Can't be," said Ron. "That's south, look, you can see a bit of the lake out of the window..."

Thus we know that the lake is south, which means that the forest on the map is indeed east.

So now we are left with the question of how the sun could be setting over the forest if the forest is in the east. The answer to this appears to be that this is an inconsistency. Indeed, elsewhere in the books we find that the sun *rises* by the forest. In *Order of the Pheonix* Harry wakes up one morning and looks out the window and we have the following description:

> Something caught Harry's attention: movement on the edge of the Forbidden Forest. Harry squinted into the sun and saw Hagrid emerging from between the trees.

As it is the early morning the sun would be in the east. As Harry squints into the sun to see the forest, it follows that the forest is in the east. This accords with its placement on the map.

The author probably just wanted to write about the sun in the forest, so she had the sun rising and setting by the forest, according to necessity, without necessarily making sure that such descriptions would always fit the actual layout of the school and grounds.