# Has J.K Rowling Ever Commented/Approved On The Position Of The Hogwarts Courtyard?

Tags: harry-potter

I am curious as to the positioning and positions of the Hogwarts grounds. It seems that with different directors of different movies, the grounds change. I do realize that the movies are supervised by J.K Rowling (to my knowledge) and she has the authority to change some things. I am talking about the positioning of the courtyard and the bridge in the seventh/eighth movie. **I would like to know if J.K Rowling ever approved/commented on this via canonical information such as documentaries, videos, or interviews etc.**

You can find a picture on the Viaduct Courtyard wiki page, or a direct picture [here](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Viaduct_Courtyard?file=Students_under_Snape.jpg).

Comment: Well, J.K. Rowling doesn't supervise the movies in a direct way, but she does, yes, have input. I believe she is often listed as a producer in the credits of the *Harry Potter* films. Would you clarify which bridge you are asking about -- is it the one that Neville and Seamus rig and blow up in movie eight? Or are you asking about a different bridge? The courtyard picture is clear, but I can't make out a bridge. :)

Comment: [Is this the picture of the bridge you're talking about?](https://www.flickr.com/photos/slytherincess/17374564511/) This is a picture of a mock up from movie eight.

Comment: [Here is the official map of Hogwarts Grounds by J K Rowling](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/images/jkr/jkr-hogwartsmap.JPG)

Comment: Yes @Slytherincess, I d o believe that that is the bridge that I am talking about. If it is connecting to the courtyard and is the main entrance to the Entrance Hall/Great Hall, then yes.

Comment: And if the duplicate-linked answer isn't enough, the second duplicate is the map here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49359/is-forbidden-forest-east-or-west-of-hogwarts